# Error installing Ruby Gem on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I've been trying to install the [jekyll-responsive-image](https://github.com/bholagabbar/jekyll-responsive-image) plugin for jekyll. When I try to install it as a gem as mentioned in the setup, I get the following error:

```
> ERROR:  Error installing jekyll-responsive_image:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> 
>     C:/Ruby23/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
> the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
> options.
> 
> Provided configuration options:
>         --with-opt-dir
>         --without-opt-dir
>         --with-opt-include
>         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>         --with-opt-lib
>         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>         --with-make-prog
>         --without-make-prog
>         --srcdir=.
>         --curdir
>         --ruby=C:/Ruby23/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME) extconf.rb:110:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
>         from extconf.rb:110:in `configure_compile_options'
>         from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
>         from extconf.rb:517:in `new'
>         from extconf.rb:517:in `<main>'
> 
> extconf failed, exit code 1
> 
> Gem files will remain installed in
> C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
> Results logged to
> C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native
> extensions.  This could take a while...
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have a look at the steps here: stackoverflow.com/a/21610123/1482694

Comment: Make a new issue [here](https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/jekyll-responsive-image/issues), please.